# Can Ubuntu 12.04 LTS/13.04 be installed on Asus K55VM-SX086D?

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, asus

I'm new to Ubuntu. Is it possible to install Ubuntu 13.04 or 12.04 on **Asus K55VM-SX086D** laptop?

Does Ubuntu work properly on the above laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](https://mylinuxexplore.blogspot.com/2012/07/finally-powerhouse-in-my-possession.html) from the Linuxed - Exploring Linux distros blog Ubuntu can be installed successfully on a Asus K55VM-SX086D laptop. The 31 comments that were posted to this blog article are also worth reading. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332026/trying-to-install-proprietory-nvidia-graphics-drivers/332035#332035) by Oli is about the same model of graphics card that is used on the Asus K55VM-SX086D laptop.

Comment: Do all the parts (Sound, touch pad, headphone) of the above laptop work properly on Ubuntu 13.04/12.04?

Comment: According to the author of the blog, "Sound is really good", although he was talking about Linux Mint which is based on Ubuntu. I didn't find any comments to the blog article about the touchpad in Ubuntu, perhaps you can add a new comment about that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I am running 12.04.3 LTS on this laptop. I have the latest Nvidia drivers that support optimus without the need for Bumblebee. Everything works wonderfully except for the brightness control either via Fn keys or brightness applet. I would advise installing 12.04.3 as it brings the raring kernel, xorg and nvidia 319 to enable nvidia-primus technology.